# how to detect when focused on internal href in jquery?

Tags: jquery

What i want to do if for an action to occur when an internal href is clicked in jquery.

Is this possible?

```
<p class ="currproj">
    <a href="#28">The Specialists Awards</a>
</p>                 
<p class ="currproj">
    <a href="#29">QA System Development</a>
</p>
```

Lowerdown in the page...

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <a id="28"></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="projimg">
            <img src="/uploads/gfx/11.png" />    
        </td>
        <td id="projimg"> <br />
           <p>25 Mar</p>    
        </td>
    </tr>                        
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <a id="29"></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

So when a user click on the href 28 if takes them to the bottom section and then i want jquery to do an alaert for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either want to look at the [hash change event with associated plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/), or bind a click to all `A` elements with an `href` attr which starts with a hash:

```
$('[href^="#"]').bind('click', function (e) {
    //your code here. do not return false, do not prevent default action on event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you mean the `hash`, i.e. `#foo-bar-baz`.

Modern browsers support the `onhashchange` event.